# Track wifi logon attempts

Tags: wi-fi

Is there any possible way to see on a rooted android device (or linux) which MAC Address tried with which Password to enter my wireless network? Also the ones who failed?

Comment: Are you talking about your devices "WiFi hotspot" – or your WiFi router? The latter certainly would be no Android issue, root or not :)

Comment: About my hotspot, I'd like to know that

Comment: Some [3rd party hotspot apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_wardrive#group_438) offer such logging features (see e.g. the screenshots of [Portable WiFi Hotspot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ng6.android.hotspot)). I'm not aware of any built-in logging using on-board capabilities.